# The Ternary Operator in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

```
$chow = 3;
echo ($chow == 1) ? "one" : ($chow == 2) ? "two" : "three";
```

output: three

```
$chow = 1;
echo ($chow == 1) ? "one" : ($chow == 2) ? "two" : "three";
```

output: two

Can anyone explain why the output is "two" when $chow = 1 instead of "one"?

Comment: So your question is only about the second code block? If yes for what is the first code block?

Comment: Please, read documentation about.

Comment: Never nest ternary operators - it leads to confusing and messy code, and often logic errors as you've seen.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-138

Answer (score 12):

This is because the ternary operator (`?:`) is [left associative](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) so this is how it's getting evaluated:

```
((1 == 1) ? "one" : (1 == 2)) ? "two" : "three"
```

So `1 == 1` -> `TRUE` means that then it's:

```
"one" ? "two" : "three"
```

And `"one"` -> `TRUE` so the output will be:

```
two
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$chow = 1;
echo ($chow == 1) ? "one" : (($chow == 2) ? "two" : "three");
```

remember to use brackets when result of operation can be unclear

now output is one

Comment: *Can anyone explain why the output is "two"* This "answer" doesn't answer the question, because it's asking for an explanation not for a solution how to get "one" as output

Comment: it's obvious that tenary operator will be evaluated from right to left

Comment: So obvious that you are even wrong! it's from left to right!  left associative means from left -> right!

Answer (score 0):

The operator is confused, you need to put brackets around your second codition. use the code below

```
$chow = 1;
echo ($chow == 1) ? "one" : (($chow == 2) ? "two" : "three"); //returns 1
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: *The operator is confused* No! This is very well defined what is happening here!

Comment: @Rizier123 actually the operator is thinking "one " as the value if it gets value 2, so putting quotes would make it simple.