# PHP isset() function returns false

Tags: php, ternary-operator, isset

Please look at my code...

```
$sample = 'done';

$sample1 = 'welcome';

echo isset($sample) ? $sample : isset($sample1) ? $sample1 : '';
```

this will returns as welcome. But how variable **$sample** is present in this sense result would be **done** .. kindly help me?

Comment: Sorry. typing mistake.. please give the answer for this

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28716043/3933332

Comment: exactly David, but now i used $sample1

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a problem with the [order of operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in your last line.  This is, in a word, confusing:

```
isset($sample) ? $sample : isset($sample1) ? $sample1 : '';
```

If you want separate conditional clauses, explicitly separate them with parentheses:

```
isset($sample) ? $sample : (isset($sample1) ? $sample1 : '');
```

Otherwise I suspect everything before the second conditional statement is collectively evaluating to `true` and thus outputting `$sample1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sample = 'done';

$sample1 = 'welcome';

echo isset($sample) ? $sample : isset($sample) ? $sample : '';
```

You're missing a **$** in front of sample1 =